# Delegate Questions

Tags: c#, constructor, delegates

I am new to C# and have **two** questions about `delegate`s.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c4bx5dk.aspx) shows that the `Delegate` class only has two constructors, both which take two arguments each. However, in the program below, I am instantiating a `Delegate` object with a seemingly one-parameter constructor (see the commented line).

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();

    static void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm inside MyMethod!");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(MyMethod); // Constructor Call
        myDelegate();
    }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

My second question is: when declaring `delegate`s with one or more parameters, why do we need to give the parameters names? In C++, we could do something like this inside classes:

```
public delegate void MyOtherDelegate(int, int, string);
```

Comment: If you have two questions then start *two* questions.  Otherwise you'll end up in a situation where some people answer one and some people answer another, and then which one gets to be the chosen answer?  It's a mess.  Avoid the situation by asking one question per question.

Comment: A language designer very well knows the complexities of ambiguity :) @EricLippert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may look like you're calling a standard constructor, but the C# compiler is actually doing a little slight of hand with your code. When you write

```
MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(MyMethod);
```

You're not actually invoking any of the constructors listed on MSDN directly. It instead calls a constructor that the compiler has automatically defined on the delegate type `MyDelegate` (these constructors are not shown on MSDN). In fact, the constructors that are listed on MSDN cannot even be called directly:

> This constructor cannot be used in application code. To create a delegate by specifying the name of an instance method, use an overload of the `CreateDelegate` method…

It's worth noting that you can even do this for brevity:

```
MyDelegate myDelegate = MyMethod;
```

As for why parameter names are necessary, perhaps they may not be strictly necessary for compilation in general, but I suspect that the designers of the CLR wanted to be consistent with other features of the in the run-time. It allows you to do things like specifying explicit parameter names that you wouldn't be able to do otherwise:

```
Func<int, int> foo = x => x + 1;
foo(arg: 1);
```

It also means you can inspect the parameter names through reflection and potentially do some useful processing with them.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answering your question but just so you are aware, C# also supports Func delegates.  in which case you don't need to even declare anything.

e.g. This method accepts a delegate with a parameter of type string and output of Int

```
public static void DoSomethingWithDelegate(Func<string, Int32> converstionDelegate)
{
    int x = converstionDelegate("1");
}
```

Read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx